# Como desligar o intellisense do visual studio 2013 apenas para Text Plan?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Preciso editar um arquivo de texto no Visual Studio 2013, mas o *intellisense* fica me perturbando dessa forma:

[image: SS]

Ao apertar espaço para a próxima palavra fica "`Troque object leitor de DVD`" e é improdutivo ficar apagando ou apertando <kbd>Esc</kbd> toda hora.

Vi algumas opções no `Tools>Options` mas são mais genéricas. Qual forma de remover esse *intellisence* de arquivos txt sem afetar nas outras linguagens? Ou melhor **desativá-lo temporariamente**?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Pior que não, desisti até, editei em outro lugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

desmarque Statement Completion para Plain Text. A extensão do arquivo é txt?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]